# How to get the Auto-assigned IP address from an Amazon Instance via aws-cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-elastic-ip

As many of you know AWS have Auto-Assigned "Public" IP's and Elastic IP's for the instances, I can get the Elastic IP's via cli with the **describe-addresses** command: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-addresses.html

Example:

```
aws ec2 describe-addresses --filters "Name=instance-id,Values=InstanceWithEIP_id" --output=json
```

And it returns the EIP but I want to know how can I get the Auto-Assigned IP via cli because the command with a instance-id from a non elastic-ip instance returns nothing.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `aws describe-instances` command instead, like so:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "Name=instance-id,Values=i-56b4192a" --output=json | jq -r '.Reservations[].Instances[].NetworkInterfaces[].Association.PublicIp'
54.111.237.129
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, as I told in the answer the command describe-addresses return nothing because the instance that I want to filter does not have an Elastic IP, instead it have an Auto-Assigned Public IP.

Comment: Sorry, just edited my answer.

Comment: as I'm working on Windows I have to delete the ' symbols: aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "Name=instance-id,Values=xxxxxxxxx" --output=json | jq -r .Reservations[].Instances[].NetworkInterfaces[].Association.PublicIp and It worked. Thanks a lot